# Logic in "-1" needed. for loop with array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```
var vacationSpots = ['Paris', 'New York', 'Barcelona'];

for(var i = vacationSpots.length - 1; i >= 0;  i--) {
console.log('I would love to visit ' + vacationSpots[i]);
}
```

Hello guys,my question is whats the logic in "-1" in the for loop to be reverse.i get it that `for(var i = vacationSpots.length; i >= 0;  i--) {` helps you running Backwards. but what's the use of -1 in printing the items in array backwards?

Comment: If you would start at `i=3`, then it'll try to get the 4th item of the array, as arrays are 0-indexed. Since the length is 1-indexed (starts at 1), you have to do `- 1` to make sure it is in range of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple ... array length is a count but indexing is zero based.

So if `myArray` length is 5 , the last index is 4 and `myArray[5]` doesn't exist.

So when iterating arrays by index you can't overshoot the last index which is  `length-1`

Comment: Just to add to that, this applies whether you're looping forwards or backwards.

Comment: i get it now. sorry im a newbie in javascript.well thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

`(vacationSpots.length)` is the length of the array but array index start from `0`. So here the `i` value is set to 2 that mean the loop will execute 3 times

Initially `i` will set to 2, so `vacationSpots[2]` will be `I would love to visit Barcelona', then`i`decremented to 1 and output will be`I would love to visit New York' & finally 0 and output will be `I would love to visit Paris`

Comment: Thank you very much bro! i get it now :)

Answer (score 1):

### In addition

There is another way for reverse loop (without '-1'):

```js
var vacationSpots = ['Paris', 'New York', 'Barcelona'];
for (var i = vacationSpots.length; i--;) {
  console.log('I would love to visit ' + vacationSpots[i]);
}
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't confuse it, I just had a brain fart.  I'll delete the comment.  Thanks for putting up with my inebriation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Index Array in Javascript start at 0, so you have vacationSpots[0]=Paris, vacationSpots[1]=New York, vacationSpots[2]=Barcelona.
vacationSpots.length is 3 so you need to print 0 1 2. In general index goes from 0 to n-1, where n = number of items (length).